# PHP decryption of VB data

Tags: php, vb.net, encryption

I am taking over a task from someone who wrote a library years ago. The library is VB and ASP.

I'm working in PHP I need to decrypt a load of strings that have been stored in a database after being encrypted in VB:

```
 Public Function Encrypt(ByVal myString As Object) As String
    If IsDBNull(myString) Or IsNothing(myString) Then
        Return String.Empty
    Else
        If myString.Length = 0 Then
            Return ""
        Else
            cryptDES3.Key = cryptMD5Hash.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myKey))
            cryptDES3.Mode = CipherMode.ECB
            Dim desdencrypt As ICryptoTransform = cryptDES3.CreateEncryptor()
            Dim MyASCIIEncoding As ASCIIEncoding = New ASCIIEncoding()
            Dim buff() As Byte = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myString)
            Return Convert.ToBase64String(desdencrypt.TransformFinalBlock(buff, 0, buff.Length))
        End If

    End If

End Function
```

The appropriate decryption function in VB is like:

```
Public Function Decrypt(ByVal myString As Object) As String
    Try
        If IsDBNull(myString) Or IsNothing(myString) Then
            Return String.Empty
        Else
            If myString.Length = 0 Then
                Return ""
            Else
                cryptDES3.Key = cryptMD5Hash.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myKey))
                cryptDES3.Mode = CipherMode.ECB
                Dim desdencrypt As ICryptoTransform = cryptDES3.CreateDecryptor()
                Dim buff() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(myString)
                Decrypt = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(desdencrypt.TransformFinalBlock(buff, 0, buff.Length))
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return "DB Error"
    End Try

End Function
```

Can anyone offer an idea as to how to decrypt the strings in PHP? I've tried all sorts of ideas suggested on here but none of them produce the actual data I'm supposed to get!

Comment: Looks like it's using Crypto - have you tried: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php

Comment: As workarounds, could you write your `decrypt` function as a REST service, callable from PHP via HTTP? Or compile it against .NET core and run it as an executable from PHP?

Comment: @MarkPhillips Good shout - I had tried it but gave it another bash and it came to life. I've edited my question to show the full code in case anyone else needs it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Although interestingly above... $block is defined but never used!

Comment: Glad you got it working :)

Comment: 1. 3DES should not be used in new work, instead use AES. 2. Do not use ECB mode, it is insecure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Instead use CBC mode with a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption.

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it has been abandonware for nearly a decade now. It has therefore been deprecated and will be removed from the core and into PECL in PHP 7.2. It does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution, are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: @zaph I don't use any of those technologies anyway - bear in mind this is legacy code (as hinted in the OP) but I did need to decrypt the data to get it migrated. The old code is gone.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I solved the problem by considering Mark's suggestion on this page. Thanks Mark. Just in case anyone else struggles:

```
$data = "my_string";
$secret  = "my_secret";
$key = md5(utf8_encode($secret), true);
$key .= substr($key, 0, 8);
$data = base64_decode($data);
$data = mcrypt_decrypt('tripledes', $key, $data, 'ecb');
$block = mcrypt_get_block_size('tripledes', 'ecb');
$len = strlen($data);
$pad = ord($data[$len-1]);
echo "Decrypted string is: " . substr($data, 0, strlen($data) - $pad);
```